# Why is right-aligned text in my navbar shifted too far to the right?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I try to display some text at the right side of a navbar. The docs state that such text must be inside a `p` tag and the classes `navbar-text` and `navbar-right` should be applied to this tag. I did this, but the text floated too far to the right. There is no space left to the right.

This is what my browser displays:
[image: Navbar]

And this is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js" th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js}"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#main-nav">
        <span class="sr-only">Navigation ein-/ausblenden</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">App</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-nav">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p class="navbar-text navbar-right">Angemeldet als Max Mustermann</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>
</body>
</html>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: working fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/D4xdE/282/

Comment: Your fiddle works for me, too. This is strange. Why could this happen?

Comment: did you changed any thing in bootstrap css? or can you create fiddle demo with your css & js

Comment: No, nothing. I posted my complete HTML file. Bootstrap is loaded from the CDN.

Comment: Do you need the text "Angemeldet als Max Mustermann" next to "Link 5" ?

Comment: I just noticed that your fiddle uses version 3.0.0. In my file I am using version 3.3.2. I changed the version and now it works. Seems that it is a bug in Bootstrap 3.3.2.

Comment: This fiddle uses version 3.3.2: http://jsfiddle.net/cfo5z4kr/

Comment: ok grt.. you got the solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because of a bug, that was introduced in Bootstrap 3.3.0. There is already an [issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/15706) as well as a [pull request](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/15744) at GitHub.

Answer (score 0):

If you want some spacing from right. You need to set `padding-right: 20px` or as you need on this class http://prntscr.com/6fde9s
or if you don't want right text just stack left to nav you need to remove this class http://prntscr.com/6fdeid
if its not work you need set `float:left !important` on `.navbar-text`